# Laravel 5.0 Session can't use static methods

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create app with Laravel 5.0 and I have problem with using Session methods in my **BaseController constructor**

Here is my BaseController with it's consturctor.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Initializer.
     *
     * @access   public
     * @return \BaseController
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        //set default lang
        if (!Session::has('lang')) {
            Session::put('lang', App::getLocale());
            Cookie::forever('lang', App::getLocale());
        } else {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('lang'));
        }


    }
}
```

but I get this error

> ContextErrorException in BaseController.php line 22:
>   Runtime Notice: Non-static method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session::has() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds strange... By the way if I was you I'd try to get around the problem by calling `Session()` as a new object. `$session = new Session()` and then `$session->has('lang')`. It's not so "Laravel style" but should work.

Comment: As you see this is Symfony2's Session object and it does not have such lousy static interface. Use Laravel's "facade" class if you want to have that: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

you should use:

```
use Session;
```

to import Session here.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem :)

Comment: How to tell visual studio that the Session exists, because it's showing  `Undefined type 'Session'` for `Session::get('something');`

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the wrong class. `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` is the class used by Laravel when you call the `Session::` facade - but they're not the same class, and Symfony's session class doesn't use a static method for `has()`. I haven't used Laravel 5 myself, but I think it's in the top-level namespace.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't notice he was importing the class. Here we go, that's why!

Answer (score -1):

**Instead of:**
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

you can use as well:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this resolve the given error?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is what the accepted answer essentially says, the only difference is you opt to use the full name rather than the alias which is an opinionated approach